# datetime.strptime unexpected behavior - locale issue

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

Wondering if anyone has a workaround for a strange error I am getting with [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

**NOTE:** not a duplicate of the timezone issue.

I am getting this exception (trimmed proprietary parts):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Jul 10 12:45:52 2016' does not match format '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
```

This exception happens during run-time on real data. But when I test it locally with the same data it works?!

You can even test yourself, The exception itself doesn't make much sense since I actually *can* use that format to match the datetime format:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = 'Jul 10 12:45:52 2016'
>>> p = '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
>>> d = datetime.strptime(s, p)
>>> print d
2016-07-10 12:45:52
```

Really not sure what is going on here. Any help appreciated. (Python 2.7.11)

Comment: `%b` is locale sensitive... are locales differing...?

Comment: @deceze What elegant python command can I use to get the locale?

Comment: See note (1) at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior: `locale.getlocale()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [deceze's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303217/datetime-strptime-unexpected-behavior?noredirect=1#comment64022991_38303217) I was able to figure out a solution to this problem.

Indeed, the issue was with the locale of the machine.

(for some background, I was validating certificates on a machine and that machines locale was different from the time stamps of the certificate)

Solution was simple, just set the locale on the machine before validating the certificates.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
```