# Python 'locale.getlocale()' gives 'unknown locale error'

Tags: python, datetime, locale

- Python 3.9.12 (32bit)
- Windows 10 (32bit)

When I tried getting a datetime object I get an error like below.

```
import datetime

dt_str = "2022-09-13 14:23:10"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_strptime.py", line 268, in <module>
  File "_strptime.py", line 182, in __init__
  File "_strptime.py", line 69, in __init__
  File "_strptime.py", line 28, in _getlang
  File "locale.py", line 593, in getlocale
  File "locale.py", line 501, in _parse_localename
ValueError
: 
unknown locale: ko-KR
"""
```

So I tried again to check out the current locale, but the same error occurred.

```
import locale
print(locale.getlocale())

"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "locale.py", line 593, in getlocale
  File "locale.py", line 501, in _parse_localename
ValueError
: 
unknown locale: ko-KR
"""
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datetime.strptime unexpected behavior - locale issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303217/datetime-strptime-unexpected-behavior-locale-issue)

Comment: @ewong No, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think your timezone isn't setup correctly.
Try using:

```py
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ko_KR.utf8')
```

Comment: I tried that and it gives 'locale.Error: unsupported locale setting'. Actually 'locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ('Korean_Korea', '949)) was successful. But I wonder why it does not afford 'ko_KR.utf8'.